# WSDL wsimport error

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a external application that has published the wsdl..I'm able to hit the wsdl in the browser but when I try to generate the java objects using WSIMPORT its failing with multiple errors.

I tried to contact the team that supports the service but they mentioned that they can't support wsimport tool..

QUestion-

1. If I'm unable to generate the classes, Is there any other to access the service?
2. I have both the wsdl and endpoint. What would be the alternative way?

Comment: A better way to frame the question would be to include the specific error you're getting